# Is there any way to use a React library in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, plotly

I am currently learning React native. I have to use heatmap -from plotly library- in react native. There is plotly library for React. In gitgub, there is react-native-plotly but doesn't include heatmap. Is there any way I can use react-plotly methods in react native?

Comment: Probably not, there are completely different components available.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a core React library, then it would need to be ported to `react-native`.

Comment: How can it be ported to react-native?

Comment: NPM is an open-source community. You'll either have to port it yourself or ask/pay someone else to do it. @brkhandler